# TypeScript before() and after() not found

Tags: typescript, testing, npm, jestjs, supertest

Trying to run tests in TypeScript with Jest/SuperTest - however when I run `npm test`, it returns these errors:

What package am I missing/not importing?

```
 FAIL  test/test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    test/test.ts:8:3 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'before'.

    8   before(PlatformTest.bootstrap(Server));
        ~~~~~~
    test/test.ts:9:3 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'before'.

    9   before(() => {
        ~~~~~~
    test/test.ts:12:3 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'after'.

    12   after(PlatformTest.reset);
```

These are my imports:

```
import {PlatformTest} from "@tsed/common";
import * as SuperTest from "supertest";
import {Server} from "../src/Server";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you chose the correct globals, in jest, there is no `after()` or `before()`, but e.g. `afterEach()` or `beforeEach()`.

All jest globals can be found here: https://jestjs.io/docs/api